# Storing lists of different case classes in memcached

Tags: mysql, scala, serialization, memcached, deserialization

Got my self stuck on a problem. I am trying to store data from a MySQL database in memcached for 5 minutes to lower calls to the database. I am trying to store the data in memcached in a List for different case classes. These are the case classes I have;

```
case class Provider(id:Int, name:String, region:String, auth_url:String, tenant:String, user:String, pass:String)

case class Plan(id:Int, name:String, price:Int, currency:String, flavor_ref:String, provider:Provider,
            cpus:Int, memory:Int, bandwidth:Int, disk:Int, priv_ips:Int, pub_ips:Int)

case class ServerGroup(id:Int, group_name:String, min_servers:Int, max_servers:Int, group_conf_id:String, plan:Plan, cloud:Provider)

case class Server(id:Int, ip:String, owner:String, config_id:String, root_user:String, root_pass:String, chefRun:Date, group:ServerGroup, plan:Plan, cloud:Provider)
```

And here is an example of how I am trying to store it in memcached

```
def getProvidersCache: List[Provider] = {
   val memcached = Memcached(Configuration("10.16.32.2:11211"), ec)

   memcached.awaitGet[List[Provider]]("pol_celestia_providers") match {
      case Some(providers) => return providers
      case None => {
        val providers = getProviders
        memcached.awaitSet("pol_celestia_providers", providers, Duration.create(300, "seconds"))
        return providers
      }
   }
 }
```

`getProviders` is a call that retrieves the data from the database and returns a `List[Providers]`

But when I compile I keep getting these errors

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Error - Scala]

Any help is welcome.

Thanks, Liam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, I did some more research into the topic and found scala/pickling, I am now using scala/pickling to convert the Lists to json and store them in memcached

e.g.

```
  def getProvidersCache: List[Provider] = {
    val memcached = Memcached(Configuration("10.16.32.2:11211"), ec)

    memcached.awaitGet[String]("pol_celestia_providers") match {
      case Some(data:String) => return (new JSONPickle(data)).unpickle[List[Provider]]
      case None => {
        val providers = getProviders
        memcached.awaitSet("pol_celestia_providers", providers.pickle.value, Duration.create(300, "seconds"))
        return providers
      }
    }
  }
```